# regex alternates values for #test even though there are no code changes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm thoroughly bothered and confused by this. The best way to explain is with the below screen shot.

I'm instantiating the regex object like so:

```
var PEPPER_STANDARD_DATE_REGEX = /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}, \d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (AM|PM) [A-Z]{1,5}/g
```

See also: https://www.regex101.com/r/jT2tG4/1

[image: extremely odd behavior]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not bug but a known behavior of `g` global flag which remembers [`RegExp.lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) position between multiple `test` or `exec` calls.

To fix it just remove `g` flag from your regex i.e.

```
/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}, \d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (AM|PM) [A-Z]{1,5}/
```

Comment: Alas, I need the global flag so I guess I'll reset `RegExp.lastIndex`